# Javascript for loop not appending list in dictionary

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dictionary

And I'm not sure I understand the problem at all.

```
var vtf=[]; // Dictionary that maps number-> list
var length;
var s; // A list of numbers with s.length = length
// length and s are set to values

for(i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    var f=s[i]; 
    if(f in vtf)
       vtf[f].push(i);
    else
       vtf[f]=[i];
}
```

So basically I check if vtf contains the value f=s[i]. If it does it appends i to the list contained at vtf[f] and if it doesn't it makes a new list with i as its only element.

The problem I get is that after running this every index of vtf only contains that first i that was added despite me knowing that almost every value saved in vtf should have a list of multiple elements.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. When I put alerts inside the if statement they don't even pop up but when I put them outside the loop, for the same value, they show it's evaluating to true a number of times.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `in` operator.

Comment: s is undefined as well

Comment: Actually, your code is correct. Please post the complete code, with `s` and `length` defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, the only thing, `vtf` should be declared as an object, not as an array:

```
var vtf={};
var s=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]; 

for(i=0; i<s.length; i++)
{
    var f=s[i]; // All values in s are numbers
    if(f in vtf)
       vtf[f].push(i);
    else
       vtf[f]=[i];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(vtf))
```

Result:

```
"{"1":[0,4],"2":[1,5],"3":[2,6],"4":[3,7]}"
```